# python-telegram-bot: Pass arguments to the bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I see some bots acts regarding args passed to the bot. For example:

```
https://t.me/name_bot?start=something
```

This is helpful for sending invitations/ referral / promo codes  etc.

How can I handle this using `python-telegram-bot` and getting the `start` value?

Is it possible to use different vars other than `start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tested it before but it seems you have it in documentation as [deep linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking).

`start=something` should run command `/start something`

Link can use only `start` or `startgroup`

---

```
import os
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

# --- init ---

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# --- commands ---

def start(update, context):
    print('text:', update.message.text)   # /start something
    print('args:', context.args)          # ['something']

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

# --- start ---
    
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```